# Is it problematic to write tests for my lexer and then use that lexer to generate data for tests for my parser?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I'm writing a small transpiler. I've written extensive tests for my lexer. But writing tests for my parser is much more difficult because the parser needs to take in a `List[Token]` while the lexer simply takes in a `str`.

Here's an example without using the lexer to generate a `List[Token]`:

```
def some_test_name():
    first_decimal_token: Token = Token(DECIMAL_TOKEN_TYPE, "86")
    multiply_token: Token = Token(MULTIPLY_TOKEN_TYPE, "*")
    second_decimal_token: Token = Token(DECIMAL_TOKEN_TYPE, "3")

    tokens: List[Token] = [
        first_decimal_token, multiply_token, second_decimal_token,
        end_of_file_token
    ]

    first_factor_node: FactorNode = FactorNode(first_decimal_token.value)
    multiply_operator: ArithmeticOperator = ArithmeticOperator.MULTIPLY
    second_factor_node: FactorNode = FactorNode(second_decimal_token.value)

    term_node: TermNode = TermNode(first_factor_node, multiply_operator,
                                   second_factor_node)

    expected_output_tokens: List[Token] = [end_of_file_token]
    expected_output: NodeSuccess = NodeSuccess(expected_output_tokens, term_node)

    node_output: NodeResult = parse_tokens_for_term(tokens)

    assert isinstance(node_output, NodeSuccess)
    assert expected_output == node_output
```

Here's what it looks like when using the lexer

```
def using_da_lexer():
    INPUT: str = "86 * 3"
    
    lexer_result: List[Token] | LexerFailure = lexer(INPUT)
    assert isinstance(lexer_result, list)

    first_decimal:token: Token = lexer_result[0]
    second_decimal_token: Token = lexer_result[2]

    first_factor_node: FactorNode = FactorNode(first_decimal_token.value)
    multiply_operator: ArithmeticOperator = ArithmeticOperator.MULTIPLY
    second_factor_node: FactorNode = FactorNode(second_decimal_token.value)

    term_node: TermNode = TermNode(first_factor_node, multiply_operator,
                                   second_factor_node)

    expected_output_tokens: List[Token] = [end_of_file_token]
    expected_output: NodeSuccess = NodeSuccess(expected_output_tokens, term_node)

    node_output: NodeSuccess | NodeFailure = parse_tokens_for_term(tokens)

    assert isinstance(node_output, NodeSuccess)
    assert expected_output == node_output
```

1. Is it problematic to use the Lexer in my tests?
2. Which approach is more scalable? If I have input like: "86 * 2 + 10 / 3" for when I am testing expressions, which approach will give me less headaches?
3. Is there any better approach to testing the parser or is it naturally going to take many lines to write comprehensive tests?

Comment: It depends on how well you are testing your lexer elsewhere. If your parser test fails, is it because the parser is broken, or because your lexer produced bad test input? Or worse, can a bad lexer output cause a parser test to incorrectly pass?

Comment: Ate you writing test to proventhungs work now, or are you writing test to catch future changes that break things

Comment: It seems to me that, not only is it acceptable, it is desirable to implement the tests of the lexer first and then the parser, treating the lexer as a black box?

Comment: @Neil To clarify, writing tests for the parser which depend on a working lexer is okay? I've written comprehensive tests for the lexer; therefore, if I write tests for the parser, I'm okay?

Comment: Treating each one as a separate sub-system, with the parser dependent on the lexer, testing mirrors development? That would probably be how I'd set it up, too. I'd like to see some more experienced developers answer this question.

Comment: If you've already built a _driver_ to test the lexer, you might use a [stub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub) to test the parser.